при вызове def функции из другого файла выходит ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax
файл info.py
async def pong(ctx):
embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x4C70D9)
embed.set_image(url="https://i.postimg.cc/kG72fxt0/Group-1.png")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)

файл bot.py
import discord
import datetime
from info import *
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'], intents=intents)


@bot.command()
pong(ctx)

bot.run(config['token'])

ошибка:
File "c:\discord_bot\bot.py", line 31
pong(context)
^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Декоратор нужно добавлять к объявлению функции, а не к вызову.

Декораторы применяются перед объявлением функции, а не перед её вызовом. Например:
@bot.command()
async def pong(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x4C70D9)   
    embed.set_image(url='...')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

